# pythonw.exe does not terminate

Tags: windows, python-2.7, twisted, python-idle

When running this code via IDLE (Python 2.7.12 on Windows 7):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.run()
```

If I press `Ctrl + C`, I get back the prompt in the IDLE shell. However `pythonw.exe` still lingers in Task Manager even after I've closed all IDLE windows. This does not happen if I execute and `Ctrl + C` the code from terminal. What is the difference and how to fix the IDLE case?

-Edit-
Same problem occurs on a different machine with Windows 10 Pro 64-bit, Python 2.7.12. Either I'm not using twisted.internet.reactor correctly or it could be a bug.

-more info-
Python 3.5.2 64-bit on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit does not have this problem. Looks like it's only with Python 2.7.12. Tested with both Twisted version 16.3.2 and 16.4.0.

Comment: If 'Task Manager' means OS is Windows, add that to your tags.  What happens if you run your code with `python -i program.py` and hit ^C?  When you get a Shell prompt after ^C, is there first a 'RESTART' line?  What is different about IDLE is that it runs its user interface and user code in separate processes.  Some programs can interfere with the communication between the two.

Comment: Running it with `python -i` then hit ^C drops me back to the Python prompt. If I execute `exit()` the process disappears from Task Manager as expected. It seems the problem only occur if the script is executed from IDLE.

Comment: What about RESTART?

Comment: There is no "RESTART" line whether it's run in the windows cmd prompt or in IDLE. `python.exe` disappears as expected if run in `cmd.exe`, whereas `pythonw.exe` lingers after all IDLE windows are closed.